# Routing path prefix in one file

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to move all my routes to one file so that when I want to add a route in the future, I don't need to create a new `Controller` class.

My code is like this right now:

In `Controller.scala`:

```
trait controller {
  def route(path: PathMatcher[Unit], port: Int) = pathPrefix(path) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In `HttpRoutes.scala`

```
route("health", 3000) ~ route("", 4000)
```

where the second part catches all other routes.

This does not seem to work because in my unit test:

```
GET("/testing") ~> c.route("/testing", 4000) ~> check {
  handled shouldBe true
}
```

handled returns false.

Comment: I figured out this one, since the function `route` takes a `pathMatcher`, in mu unit test, I should have `c.route("", 4000)` rather than `c.route("/testing", 4000)` to be able to catch all traffics.